# One to many Generic Listview Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'am new to Django. I have a one to many relationship -

Example: A CustomUser can have one to many Memberships.

I want to create a view that shows a list of all the Memberships for a specfic CustomUser. I tried the Generic ListView with no success, it only shows a list of all the meberships in the Membership Table and not memberships for a specific user.

**Model:**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True,)
    personal_Id = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField('middle name', max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def full_name(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.first_name, self.middle_name, self.last_name)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

class Membership(models.Model):
    CustomUser = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Membeship_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    reg_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) 
    start_date = models.DateTimeField('start date')
    end_date = models.DateTimeField('end date')
    member_type= (
    ('Y', "Year"),
    ('Q', "Quarter"),
    ('H', "Half-Year"),
    )
    membership_type = models.CharField(choices=member_type, max_length=10)
```

**View**

```
class MemberShipIndex(generic.ListView):
    model = Membership
    template_name = 'members/membership_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'membership_list'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MemberShipIndex, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

**URL**

```
path('<int:pk>/membership/', views.MemberShipIndex.as_view(), name='MemberShipIndex'),
```

**HTML**

```
 {% for Membership in membership_list %}
                          <tr>
                           
                              <td>{{ Membership.Membeship_id }}</td>
                              <td>{{ Membership.reg_date }}</td>
                              <td>{{ Membership.start_date }}</td>
                              <td>{{ Membership.end_date }}</td>
                          </tr>
                          {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to overwrite `get_queryset` of the generic `ListView`. For example:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

You can refer to the documentation for further details:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/

Comment: Thanks, the thing is that i pass the pk for the user in the url. Your suggestion shows all the membeship items for current logged in user.

Comment: For only one specific user or for all users?

Comment: No for the specific user, the user thats logged in. I want to create som sort of admin dashbord so i want to be able to fetch all memberships for a spoecific user. Is that possiable? i

Comment: You should be able to see this on the admin page. Or do you want the user to also see this page? I think it's dangerous to have the pk in the url, because then anyone can access that page...

Comment: I understand the concern, yes i can se this in admin. I want to build a front end that show a list of users. After that i want to have a view that shows a list of meberships for a specific user. Is you suggestion to let Django admin handle everythin and present only current user in Frontend?